# How can I run Cron job every 5 days

Tags: cron

I have 5 shell scripts, I want to run them in 5 days cycle, like follows:

Day 1 :  script 1
   Day 2 :  script 2
   Day 3 :  script 3
   Day 4 :  script 4
   Day 5 :  script 5

Day 6 :  script 1
   Day 7 :  script 2
   Day 8 :  script 3
   Day 9 :  script 4
   Day 10 :  script 5

And keep the scripts runing in 5 day cycle. How can I set it in cron jobs?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382634/how-to-set-cronjob-for-2-days)

Answer (score 8):

`cron` by itself doesn't support this. The eariest way to accomplish what you want is probably to ask `cron` to execute a dispatcher script every day (at the same time) and have the dispatcher script decide which other script to run based on what day it is. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $(expr $(date +%s) / 86400 % 5) in
   0)
       exec /script/for/day/1
       ;;
   1)
       exec /script/for/day/2
       ;;
   2)
       exec /script/for/day/3
       ;;
   3)
       exec /script/for/day/4
       ;;
   4)
       exec /script/for/day/5
       ;;
esac
```

Comment: +1, I like the `expr` trick to get the day since epoch.

Comment: Arithmetic expansion is in all POSIX shells: `$(($(date +%s) / 86400 % 5))`. Beware that depending on the time at which this command runs and the DST rules in your timezeone, I think there's a possibility that you'll skip or repeat a day on a DST changeover.

Comment: @Gilles That's always a possibility if you schedule cron jobs between 1:00 and 2:00 local time in a timezone with DST (once a year those times don't exist, and once a year they occur twice), so just avoid those times, or campaign for the abolishment of DST (I wish you success!). This trick neither improves or worsens that because it's based on the UTC day.